# How to fix invalid hexlify value error in ethers.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, ethers.js

```
Error: invalid hexlify value (argument="value", value="PRIVATE_KEY", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)
```

I encountered an error while building an application to send a token from one wallet to another using Ethers.js and Node.js. I am using a private key for the token transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Answer:

Please carefully check your PRIVATE KEY. It should be a 64-character string, so make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to use the prefix "0x", but the outcome remained the same.
I tried to both update and downgrade the version of ethers.js, but it didn't help me.